# Convert files to PDF when uploading to media library

Tags: media-library, pdf

Is there any built-in mechanism to convert files to PDFs when uploading them to the media library, or does someone know of functionality that can accomplish same?

Comment: Could you please specify further what type of "files" you would like to convert to PDF? Also for which version of Sitecore?

Comment: This question lacks sufficient detail to be able to answer in a meaningful way apart from "No, there is nothing OOTB, yes you can do anything you want in Sitecore". More detail and what you have tried so far would be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way to do this.

You can build a module that converts the files to PDF using iTextSharp, PhantomJS or Puppeteer.

Once upon a time @adamnaj wrote a [script to export media items](https://gist.github.com/AdamNaj/e24930984da535359490) to PDF using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions. Maybe you can use that idea to import them back into the media library after PDF generation.